# OS X AppEngine - ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

Tags: python, google-app-engine

UPDATE: This is a problem I am having with the 1.8.0 App Engine SDK on a fresh install of OS X 10.8.3.

First up - there's a bunch of questions on SO with a similar title. I've checked them out, and I don't believe they answer my question. Mostly they recommend getting libsqlite3-dev and rebuilding python to get _sqlite3.so, but that's already where it should be:

```
$ find / -name _sqlite3.so
Password:
...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

The actual code that that causes app engine SDK to try to load that module is:

```
remaining = TaskSetElement.all().filter('taskSet', ts_key).filter('complete', False).count()
```

Here's the SDK stack trace:

```
  File "~/dev/myApp/myApp/task.py", line 90, in completeTaskSetElement
    remaining = TaskSetElement.all().filter('taskSet', ts_key).filter('complete', False).count()
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2133, in count
    result = raw_query.Count(limit=limit, **kwargs)
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1698, in Count
    batch = self.GetBatcher(config=config).next()
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2754, in next
    return self.next_batch(self.AT_LEAST_ONE)
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2791, in next_batch
    batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Users/colin/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2528, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1222, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 570, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/Users/colin/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 856, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I've got a bunch of datastore code prior to this line that's executing fine. I get the same problem running dev_appserver.py directly from the command line or in eclipse with pydev. 

From the command line, everything looks good:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import _sqlite3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

This code snippet (running in app engine SDK) removes the app engine datastore code from the equation:

```
...
logging.info("Python Version: %s" % sys.version)
logging.info(filter(lambda p: 'lib-dynload' in p, sys.path))

import sqlite3
...
```

It outputs this:

```
INFO     2013-05-26 05:55:12,055 main.py:38] Python Version: 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
INFO     2013-05-26 05:55:12,055 main.py:40] ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
ERROR    2013-05-26 05:55:12,058 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in 
    import sqlite3
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
  File "~/dev/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 856, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like adding `'_sqlite3'` to the `_WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES` list at line 742 in sandbox.py (which lives at `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python` on my machine) has worked for me for now.

To my uneducated eye it looks like `CModuleImportHook` is incorrectly blocking the import of _sqlite3 and that modifying any one of the checks it has to return `None` removes the error. Someone with more nous - please expand on what I've said or correct me!

That change may allow you to import _sqlite3 in your own code, which would be a mistake. Perhaps it needs a way to limit the import to dbapi2.py?

Comment: Perfect! I'm running actually running the linux GAE SDK distribution via eclipse, but the solution works just fine there as well - thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. That issue had been bugging me too for ages!

Answer (score 2):

From you stack trace it shows you are trying to import sqlite in your main.py.

Why are you doing this?

Importing sqlite is not supported in appengine.  sqlite is implemented with a binary library and you can't just import any old binary. In addition the filesystem is read only, you couldn't write to sqlite db.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the data store in the local dev server is implemented using SQLite, so the import happens within App Engine code, not his own (see last code snippet in the question).

Comment: Correct - App engine imports sqlite in the sdk to support the dev datastore - this is a problem I have in my dev environment. The import in my own code was only to demonstrate the problem (it is not for production deployment), printing out the python version and showing that the path included what it should in my runtime environment. My test code was built after first looking at the app engine code - i.e. I'm importing the same thing to generate the same error.

Comment: I've modified the question put the SDK issue first, and included the stack trace from app engine, as well as from my demo code. I found this issue, which is potentially related: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9008 - comments on March 26 & April 27 for the same problem.

Comment: Well including a small stacktrace, showing an explicit import of sqlite on line 42 is certainly confusing things.

Comment: Perhaps - the intention is to highlight that the problem appears independent of the datastore. Usually when asking a question, the advice is to construct a simple case that demonstrates the problem. Hopefully I've edited the question sufficiently to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Except that is exactly the wrong test case, and hides the real problem.  As I mentioned it's not possible to import sqlite in appengine.

Comment: Well, it highlights exactly what the problem is - a failure to successfully import sqlite in the dev appserver environment, logging the actual python version and showing the right entry in the system path. It also removes elements that don't appear to be part of the problem, such as calls to the datastore. I'm not sure why you're focussed on the prod environment - nothing in my question makes sense there (e.g. running the python interpreter from the cmd line, executing sudo find, and yes - explicitly importing sqlite). Perhaps I'm mistaken though - what do you think the 'real problem' is?

Comment: All I am saying is you clouded your real issue with the explicit import in main.py (which would never work) with your original stacktrace.  And my original answer was in response to the information you provided.

Comment: In the interests of clarity - the import *should* work in the dev environment. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

You mention this is a fresh install of OSX. I wonder if you used Homebrew to build Python? Doing Brew-update or brew-upgrade caused me similar problems to this, although not on GAE. You might find https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17312 useful.