# Python sqllite3 with bottle framework on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite, bottle

Not a duplicate. According to what is written under [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411030/how-to-unpack-sqlite3-database-written-by-google-appengine-bulk-downloader)  import sqlite3 should work under GAE. However, import sqlite3 in my script throws the following error (after putting sqlite3 for Python27 instead of sqlite3 for Python34 in the app directory I managed to omit the previous error, described at the bottom):

```
import sqlite3

File "d:\python\jcifapp\jcifapp_ver6\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from dbapi2 import *
File "d:\python\jcifapp\jcifapp_ver6\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 950, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I presume that putting _sqlite3 could solve the issue or at least move it forward. Since import sqlite3 perfectly works under Py27 and Py34 installed on my machine, scripts launched from my computer must have access to _sqlite3. I only found _sqlite3.lib in Python27\libs (I am using Windows) but putting this file into the app directory doesn't help. Does anyone know how to make import sqlite3 under GAE working, as it seems that it should be possible judging from the post under the above-mentioned link?

I have been developing an app with bottle framework collecting data via userforms and storing/retrieving it in/from the sqlite database. Everything works fine locally but after deploying all files to Google App Engine I get logs indicating at problems with importing modules related to sqlite3 module:

```
  File "D:\python\jcifapp\jcifapp_new\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>

     *from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "D:\python\jcifapp\jcifapp_new\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 25, in <module>
     import collections.abc
  ImportError: No module named abc
  INFO     2015-08-25 22:32:14,997 module.py:808] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -*
```

I have tried putting sqlite3 module into the projects directory but to no avail. When I run Python scripts locally I encounter no problems with importing sqlite3. I have also no problems deploying to GAE and running from there apps which don't use sqlite3.
Does anyone have a clue how to make GAE work with sqlite3?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use SQLite libraries on google app engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555490/can-i-use-sqlite-libraries-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that solved my problem:
[OS X AppEngine - ImportError: No module named _sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757013/os-x-appengine-importerror-no-module-named-sqlite3)
Adding '_sqlite3' to _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES in sandbox.py also worked for Win7.